# Elasticsearch group by field for getting first occurrence of value

Tags: python, elasticsearch

Sorry if my question might be a duplicate, I just didn't find anything similar.

I send requests to the Elasticsearch through Python.

Here is my code:

```
import json
import requests

query = {
 "size": 5,
 "_source": ["UserId", "Name", "Status"],
 "query": {
   "match_all": {
   }
 }
}

query = json.dumps(query) 

response = requests.get(f'{ES_URL}/{ES_INDEX}/_search',
                        headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
                        data=query)
```

This is my response:

```
{'took': 16,
 'timed_out': False,
 '_shards': {'total': 5, 'successful': 5, 'skipped': 0, 'failed': 0},
 'hits': {'total': 2069099,
  'max_score': 1.0,
  'hits': [{'_index': 'index2',
    '_type': 'indexresult',
    '_id': '8768768',
    '_score': 1.0,
    '_source': {'UserId': 4264151, 'Name': 'Victor', 'Status': 'High'}},
   {'_index': 'index2',
    '_type': 'indexresult',
    '_id': '5463255',
    '_score': 1.0,
    '_source': {'UserId': 4264151, 'Name': 'Victor', 'Status': 'Medium'}},
   {'_index': 'index2',
    '_type': 'indexresult',
    '_id': '2323564',
    '_score': 1.0,
    '_source': {'UserId': 4327653, 'Name': 'John', 'Status': 'Medium'}},
   {'_index': 'index2',
    '_type': 'indexresult',
    '_id': '3564123',
    '_score': 1.0,
    '_source': {'UserId': 4327653, 'Name': 'John', 'Status': 'Low'}},
   {'_index': 'index2',
    '_type': 'indexresult',
    '_id': '4456256',
    '_score': 1.0,
    '_source': {'UserId': 7893231, 'Name': 'Sebastian', 'Status': 'Low'}]}}
```

The response contains two repetitions of the values of `UserId` (`4264151` and `4327653`).

**Question**: What needs to be written in the Elasticsearch query to get only the unique `UserId` values (e.g. return the random or first occurrence of `UserId`)?

That is, I want the response to look something like this:

```
{'took': 16,
 'timed_out': False,
 '_shards': {'total': 5, 'successful': 5, 'skipped': 0, 'failed': 0},
 'hits': {'total': 2069099,
  'max_score': 1.0,
  'hits': [{'_index': 'index2',
    '_type': 'indexresult',
    '_id': '8768768',
    '_score': 1.0,
    '_source': {'UserId': 4264151, 'Name': 'Victor', 'Status': 'High'}},
   {'_index': 'index2',
    '_type': 'indexresult',
    '_id': '2323564',
    '_score': 1.0,
    '_source': {'UserId': 4327653, 'Name': 'John', 'Status': 'Medium'}}
   {'_index': 'index2',
    '_type': 'indexresult',
    '_id': '4456256',
    '_score': 1.0,
    '_source': {'UserId': 7893231, 'Name': 'Sebastian', 'Status': 'Low'}]}}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [field collapsing and expanded results](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html#_expand_collapse_results):

Rewrite your query to the below below and for each user you'll get one single document:

```
query = {
  "size": 5,
  "_source": false
  "query": {
    "match_all": {
    }
  },
  "collapse" : {
    "field" : "UserId", 
    "inner_hits": {
        "name": "last", 
        "size": 1, 
        "_source": ["UserId", "Name", "Status"],
        "sort": [{ "_id": "desc" }] 
    }
  }
}
```